# Mysql: Calculate % increase/decrease when a specific date difference is matched

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find out what is the average percentage increase in salary that an worker can expect after working for 2 years.

```
Table workers
+-----------+------------+
| worker_id | hire_date  |
+-----------+------------+
|  10001    | 1986-06-26 |
|  10002    | 1996-08-03 |
+-----------+------------+

Table salaries
+-----------+--------+------------+------------+
| worker_id | salary | from_date  | to_date    |
+-----------+--------+------------+------------+
|  10001    |  60117 | 1986-06-26 | 1987-06-26 |
|  10001    |  62102 | 1987-06-26 | 1988-06-25 |
|  10001    |  66074 | 1988-06-25 | 1989-06-25 |
|  10001    |  66596 | 1989-06-25 | 1990-06-25 |
|  10001    |  66961 | 1990-06-25 | 1991-06-25 |
|  10002    |  65828 | 1996-08-03 | 1997-08-03 |
|  10002    |  65909 | 1997-08-03 | 1998-08-03 |
|  10002    |  67534 | 1998-08-03 | 1999-08-03 |
|  10002    |  69366 | 1999-08-03 | 2000-08-02 |
+-----------+--------+------------+------------+
```

Currently, I have this query but I'm not getting any result. Can you help me?

```
SELECT YEAR(hire_date), YEAR(from_date), MAX(salary)-MIN(salary)
FROM salaries JOIN workers using(worker_id)
WHERE YEAR(hire_date)-YEAR(from_date) = 2;
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Did the below solution work for you?

Comment: Btw, `YEAR(hire_date)-YEAR(from_date)` will never be positive.

Comment: People are downvoting and voting to close a question that is well-formed, has sample data, and an attempt by the OP.  I don't get it.  That's not very welcoming.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you for your help, I really appreciate it. I'm not quite getting what the two last lines do. Are they checking if the person worked there for exactly 2 years?

Comment: Yes @DanielMarcus! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want the salary on the date someone was hired and the salary two years after that.

Basically, you want to look up the salary for each worker twice, and then perform some arithmetic:

```
select avg(s2.salary - s.salary)
from workers w join
     salaries s
     on s.worker_id = w.worker_id and s.start_date = w.hire_date join
     salaries s2
     on s2.worker_id = w.worker_id and
        w.start_date + interval 2 year >= s2.start_date and
        w.start_date + interval 2 year < s2.to_date;
```

If you want a percentage increase, then it would be more like:

```
select avg( (s2.salary / s.salary) - 1)
```